# Android: Can't able to import GoogleApiClient in Eclipse

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have imported BaseGameUtil library.
But I can't able to import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient

Even I have added google-play-services-lib in this library.
I had set Google APis 4.1.2 as a project target.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to import this. 
Just Import

> import *com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper*;

then create

> GameHelper gameHelper;

setup it like this

```
if (gameHelper == null) {
    gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
    gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
}

gameHelper.setup(this);
```

and get **GoogleApiClient** this way

```
gameHelper.getApiClient()
```

Comment: Setup gameHelper isnt necessarily. Its just a bonus to my answer :)

Comment: I am not asking this.I have downloaded BaseGameUtil library from this link [https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples] and on importing this library in eclipse I am getting the above mentioned error.